# How to re-enable drag and drop in a GtkTreeView after sorting?

Tags: c, gtk

I'm using a GtkTreeView. By default, this widget supports drag and drop. However, if you sort it by one of the columns, the drag and drop is disabled (which is logical and how I would expect it to work).

I want a way to clear the sorting (I don't care about the actual rows, just clear the arrow from the column header) and re-enable drag and drop. I tried calling gtk_tree_view_set_reorderable (tree_view, TRUE), but this doesn't seem to do the trick.